# How to define a salary rule that is calculated once in Odoo 11 Payroll module

Tags: odoo, odoo-11

I want to define a salary rule in Odoo Payroll that will be calculated once and after calculation, it will not be calculated for next month's payslips. For example, a Bonus is paid once a year and is about 25% of the total salary. How I can define such rules in payroll.

Thanks,
Ata

Answer (score 0):

You can add a **python condition** (assuming you want to define the rule in xml data file):

```
<field name="condition_select">python</field>
```

and then the condition needs to indicate, depending on your context (this will allow the rule to be calculated once a year in January) it should be:

```
<field name="condition_python">datetime.today().month == 01</field>
```

and the amount is **computed this way**:

```
<field name="amount_python_compute">contract.wage * 0.25</field>
```